Is it possible to establish a purely options-based portfolio that is completely neutral to changes in asset prices?
I found that the implied volatility of 10008162 is relatively high, while the implied volatility of 10007955 is relatively low. Therefore, I want to go long on 10007955 and short on 10008162, aiming to profit from the decreasing difference in implied volatility between the two options.
However, I do not want to take on the risk of price fluctuations in the underlying asset. Therefore, I have constructed a delta-neutral and gamma-neutral pure options portfolio. This options portfolio also includes two long-dated call option contracts.My goal is to achieve immunity to price fluctuations in the underlying asset throughout the entire holding period of the portfolio, without needing to adjust the option positions in the portfolio!



code
price
IV
Delta
Gamma
Vega
Theta
Strike Price




10007955.SH
0.082
0.2693
0.512
1.9204
0.0031
-0.0022
2.75


10008162.SH
0.0109
0.4892
0.0691
0.3526
0.001
-0.0013
3.4


10008264.SH
0.235
0.2411
0.5623
0.7097
0.0089
-0.0006
2.75


10008265.SH
0.2151
0.2449
0.5273
0.7068
0.009
-0.0007
2.8






code
position




10007955.SH
12140610000


10008162.SH
-65729200000


10008264.SH
-47831560000


10008265.SH
47831560000



The above data and positions are as of October 31, 2024. You will find that the delta and gamma of this options portfolio are indeed both zero！
The following are the delta and gamma data for this portfolio as of November 1.



code
price
position
delta
Gamma
Portfolio delta
Portfolio Gamma




10007955.SH
0.0912
12140610000
0.5485
1.9142
6659124585
23239555662


10008162.SH
0.0102
65729200000
0.0671
0.3565
-4410429320
-23432459800


10008264.SH
0.2494
47831560000
0.5754
0.6883
-27522279624
-32922462748


10008265.SH
0.2301
47831560000
0.542
0.6858
25924705520
32802883848






sum
651121161
-312483038



It is clear that this portfolio already has exposure to delta and gamma risks. Therefore, it is no longer possible to be immune to changes in the underlying asset's price. As a result, the purpose of constructing this portfolio cannot be achieved! However, I still want to know if it is possible to achieve immunity to price movements in the underlying asset by constructing a pure options portfolio. This portfolio must be long on 10007955 while being short on 10008162!
Now I am concerned whether such a portfolio exists theoretically？
For example, can adding Greeks like DgammaDspot and DvegaDvol increase the number of equations in a linear system, and can adding more long-dated option contracts increase the number of columns in the linear system (effectively increasing the dimension of the null space of an underdetermined system)? Just considering delta and gamma neutrality is equivalent to a second-order Taylor expansion, which may not fit the "option price - underlying asset price" curve accurately enough. Would incorporating higher-order Greeks significantly reduce the sensitivity of the options portfolio to changes in the underlying asset price, ultimately achieving immunity of the options portfolio to fluctuations in the underlying asset price?

We do not read hallucinations from chatGPT.

It sounds like what you want is a variance swap which has a static hedge comprised of calls and puts.

The chatGPT output unfortunately does not do justice to your question. I hope chatGPT doesn't become a regular guest here. Hence my vote to close.
Having said this, if you want to have no sensitivity to stock price throughout the option holding period, I think that basically means you do not want sensitivity to the stock price at all orders. No delta, no gamma, no dgamma/dspot etc.
That will be quite difficult to achieve with only a discrete number of options. In theory you'd need an infinite number of options and I suspect you'll end up then with some sort of pure volatility derivative. However that might defeat the purpose of your trade, as the skew is sensitive to the spot price.
Conclusion: I don't think you can achieve skew exposure without some exposure to price movement.
Nuance: part of the 'skew' is actually due to vol of vol. You can capture vol of vol without exposure to spot price, but this might be taking your question a step too far.

I hope chatGPT doesn't become a regular guest here. Hence my vote to close.------I provide ChatGPT content in the hope that it can inspire the respondents. However, if it violates the forum’s rules, I am willing to delete the GPT content. I wonder if this would allow you to vote to reopen this question?

In theory you'd need an infinite number of options …………-----------Is there any related theory that has discussed this issue and reached a clear conclusion? If so, do you know which book or paper provides proof or explanation of this conclusion?

No. chatGPT won't inspire the respondents. Thank god the majority of users here is smart enough to withstand such temptations.

Sure you can. Enter a synthetic (long call, short put) long at one strike and enter a synthetic short (short call, long put) at a higher strike. You are now totally immunised against market movement.

IMO this "trivial solution" shows that the problem has not been formulated properly.
